# Error 'Class 'ZipArchive' not found' in laravel-5.8 with maatwebsite/excel

Tags: laravel-5.8, apt-get, maatwebsite-excel

Error `Class 'ZipArchive' not found` with maatwebsite/excel export table users in laravel.
I've already tried `sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip`, but that gives `sudo: apt-get: command not found`. So is there an other way than `sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip` to solve it? Or how can I solve the `sudo: apt-get: command not found` problem?

Comment: Which the OS you are trying to run `sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip` and isn't works?

Comment: I'm trying to run it with Apple macOS, @JeanMarcos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you php don't have the zip extension built in. Try this follow step to install a version with the extension:

```
brew update
brew install php@7.3
brew link php@7.3
```